# Zend: Execute something before a controller is executed

Tags: php, zend-framework, controllers, bootstrapping

In my Zend framework project I want to check whether a cookie is set. If it is the case I want to use the cookie contents to login a user.

Since it is neccessary for me to do this automatic login before any controller is called I tried to put it in the Bootstrap. There I want to check the database if the user information is valid. Unfortunately at this point the default database adapter is not yet initialized.

So my question is the following: Where do I put those stuff that should be executed before any controller is called and after all initializing/bootstrapping stuff is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'have not a great experience with Zend Framework but I think you should create a custom generic controller for example GenericController that extends the Zend_Controller_Action and put your code in the preDispatch() function. All your controllers will then a subclass of your custom controller, for example:

```
class GenericController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
   function preDispatch(){
      parent::preDispatch();
      // put your code here
   }
}
class FooController extends GenericController{
...
}
```

Comment: great, exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Better way: Use [Zend_Controller_Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html). Inheriting your controllers make debugging and configuration much harder as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods:

```
init()
// and
preDispatch()
```

implement them in your class, init runs at creation, predispatch runs right before your action method iirc

[api](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html)

On that page I linked above it states

> > Note: Usage of init() vs. preDispatch()
> >     In the previous section, we introduced the init() method, and in this section, the preDispatch() method. What is the difference between them, and what actions would you take in each?
> >     The init() method is primarily intended for extending the constructor. Typically, your constructor should simply set object state, and not perform much logic. This might include initializing resources used in the controller (such as models, configuration objects, etc.), or assigning values retrieved from the front controller, bootstrap, or a registry.
> >     The preDispatch() method can also be used to set object or environmental (e.g., view, action helper, etc.) state, but its primary purpose is to make decisions about whether or not the requested action should be dispatched. If not, you should then _forward() to another action, or throw an exception.
> >     Note: _forward() actually will not work correctly when executed from init(), which is a formalization of the intentions of the two methods.

Comment: But i want to execute my code before any controller is called. I want to login the user before Controller1 is called but also before Controller2 is called.

Comment: @ralle A controller of some sort is always called for every request. You'll have to log them in on each controller, even if you extend as suggested in the other answer you're still going to be putting these methods in. There is NO (without editing Zend) global location (besides bootstrap) for doing this. And like you said since it's the user auth, putting int he bootstrap isn't the easiest. Though you could load the DB in the bootstrap THEN do the authentication.